# Eclipse formatter putting method on new line despite enough space in line width

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 and Eclipse formatter takes this code:

```
            users = getSingleColUserList(new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream),
                            userId, profCol);
```

and drops the method call onto a new line:

```
            users =
                    getSingleColUserList(new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream),
                            userId, profCol);
```

As you can see, the line width is not the issue. It's not at all obvious what setting in the formatter dialog I need to change.

**[UPDATED *after Seelenvirtuose's answer*]**

I can set Eclipse to format `Line Wrapping -> Assignments` to `Do not wrap`. However that raises another issue with lines then not getting wrapped when they go over the line width:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> emailMap = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(DBQueries.LOAD_EMAILS);
```

The line width is 80 which is either the s or the . of DBQueries so it should be:

```
    List<Map<String, Object>> emailMap = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(
                    DBQueries.LOAD_EMAILS);
```

None of the settings that I have tested for `Line Wrapping -> Function Calls -> Arguments`

It's cute that my browser is currently displaying a scrollbar under the unwrapped code!

Answer (score 2):

It is the formatter's setting for "Line Wrapping -> Assignments". Set it to "Do not wrap".

[image]

Comment: I obviously put too much emphasis on the phrase "where necessary". I figured it was absolutely unnecessary to wrap the line after the = sign, so I didn't even test it. Thanks for enlightening me.

Comment: I was too quick off the mark with my response and acceptance there - I just came across some more code which is now going over the line width and not wrapping. I'll leave the up-vote on your answer but I can't accept it. I'll put the issue in the question.

Comment: I know that line breaking now takes place before the point of a _qualified_ function call. But I see it as wanted, as you now can chain method calls in a very readable way. Consider something like `String s = new StringBuilder(...).append(...).append(...).append(...).toString()`. This will put all `.append(...)` calls underneath.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are trying to answer my question or just adding more info, because I agree with you: line breaks in a long chain of `StringBuilder` `append` calls are totally necessary. But it doesn't address the problem that there are now no line breaks in the second example.

Comment: Oh, my setting about line breaks in function arguments do what they are supposed to do. For your example they break before the "." in `jdbcTemplate.queryForList`.

Comment: I still don't think I understand what you mean. can you put that .append() example in your answer so I can see what your format is?